# pyspark: remove rows that have duplicated values for a given field

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame:

```
field_A | field_B | field_C | field_D
  cat   |  12     |   black | 11
  dog   | 128     |   white | 19
  dog   |  35     |  yellow | 20
  dog   |  21     |   brown |  4
 bird   |  10     |    blue |  7
  cow   |  99     |   brown | 34
```

---

Is it possible to filter out the rows which have duplicated values in field_A. That is, I want the final data frame to be:

```
field_A | field_B | field_C | field_D
  cat   |  12     |   black | 11
 bird   |  10     |    blue |  7
  cow   |  99     |   brown | 34
```

Is this possible in pyspark? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create data

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,10), (0,20), (1,2), (2,1), (3,5), (3,18), (4,15), (5,18)])
t = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"])
t.collect()
```

> [Row(id=0, score=1),
>    Row(id=0, score=10),
>    Row(id=0, score=20),
>    Row(id=1, score=2),
>    Row(id=2, score=1),
>    Row(id=3, score=5),
>    Row(id=3, score=18),
>    Row(id=4, score=15),
>    Row(id=5, score=18)]

Get counts of the rows with a given id

```
idCounts = t.groupBy('id').count()
```

Join idCounts back onto original data frame

```
out = t.join(idCounts,'id','left_outer').filter('count = 1').select(['id', 'score'])
out.collect
```

> [Row(id=1, score=2),
>    Row(id=2, score=1),
>    Row(id=4, score=15),
>    Row(id=5, score=18)]

Comment: Sure can with this `out = t.join(idCounts,'id','left_outer').withColumnRenamed('count', 'newNameOfColumn')`. The select statement from my answer was used to keep just id/score (and to drop count). Note too, that without the filter statement, you'll have all the rows from the original DF (including duplicates)